Handling new password challenge from Cognito within NextAuth
I'm developing a Next.js application using NextAuth for managing session/authentication and AWS Cognito as the user pool.
I'm having trouble when is the first time the user tries to log in as AWS Console sets a temp password and the user needs to put their own.
Issue comes when I call the method completeNewPasswordChallenge. It returns an error: Missing required parameter Session. I'm throwing an error when the user needs to change their password and catch it on the client component and redirect to a form where the user input their new password.
When I submit the form. I got the error

    async authorize(credentials) {
       [...]

        return new Promise<CognitoUser | null>((resolve, reject) => {
          const user = new AwsCognitoUser({
            Username: email,
            Pool: userPool,
          })

          const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
            Username: email,
            Password: password,
          })

          user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
            onSuccess: result => {
              resolve({
                id: result.getIdToken().payload.sub,
                email,
                accessToken: result.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
                idToken: result.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
                refreshToken: result.getRefreshToken().getToken(),
                permissions: result.getIdToken().payload['custom:permission'].split(','),
              })
            },
            onFailure: err => {
              reject(new Error(err.message || 'Authentication failed'))
            },
            newPasswordRequired: () => {
              reject(new Error('NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED'))
            },
          })
        })

       [...]
    }

On the client I have:
const onSubmit = () => {
  const user = new AwsCognitoUser({
      Username: email,
      Pool: userPool,
    })

    if (!newPassword) {
      setError('Password is required')
      setIsLoading(false)
      return
    }

    user.completeNewPasswordChallenge(
      newPassword,
      {},
      {
        onSuccess: () => {
          fetcher('api/menu/dashboard')) // load menu on login success
       }
     )
}

